# extremely large xml file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have a 17gb xml file. I want to store it in MySQL. I tried it using xmlparser in php but it says maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded and inserts only a few rows. I even tried in python using element tree but it is taking lot of memory gives memory error in a laptop of 2 GB ram. Please suggest some efficient way of doing this.

Comment: OMG... Is this file a dump of database? `о_0` I might suggest to parse it manuallt with [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/set-time-limit) somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Python's `xml.sax` or [lxml.etree](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk)'s `iterparse()`.

These are "event-driven" methods of parsing xml. You tell the parser which "node" you want to listen for, and it triggers a function each time it finds that node.

This will keep your memory usage very low, and avoid the errors you are getting.

Comment: Hey, is there a faster way because it is still in progress since 14 hours.

Comment: The disk/xml shouldn't be the bottleneck.  I suggest you test the time it takes or the rate at which you can read the xml elements and debug from there.  If you are committing after every statement, that will slow things waaay down.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, turn off execution time limit in PHP (e.g. use a CLI script) and be patient. If you say it starts to insert something into database from a 17 GB file, it's actually doing a good job already. No reason to hasten it for such one-time job. (Increase memory limit too, just in case. Default 128 Mb is not that much.)